# 255 Character limitation for a Textbox in Sharepoint List

Tags: list, infopath

I have a list that I am customizing using Infopath 2010. Do you have any idea how to overcome the 255 char limitation for a text box? I understand that this is possible for document libraries. When you create a new column of type Multiple Lines of Text, you get the option to select the ‘Allow unlimited length in document libraries’ check box. However this is not possible for lists.

Is there a solution other than using a rich text box which is not supported by all web browsers. Multiple text boxes are not not an option too.

Please help! Thank you in advance,

Anas

Comment: I had the same problem, and the fix did work, unfortunately my form is tied to a K2 and it broke my workflow.. I'll let you know if I find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what order are you creating the field. Did you create the list first with all of the fields or did you create some of the items and then select customize form in InfoPath and then add additional fields through the form? Or are you creating a custom InfoPath form for a library. The reason I ask these questions is because if you had created the list first with all of the fields then you should have selected a multiline text with plain text as the field choice. A multiline text field is the only way to get past the 255 character text limit. If you create a text box in the form without having it first available in the list then the text box will just show as a single line of text. However you could then go into the list settings and change the field to mutliline text and just set it to plain text.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was helpful. I created the field from list settings. I selected a multiline text with plain text as field choice. Then I opened my sharepoint list using Infopath and added the field to my form. The 255 character text limit is gone.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a text box in InfoPath using the controls items at the top the text is created with "Data type: TextType", which is limited to 255 charectors. However if you create a text box using list settings or adding a field using the actions on the right the data type is different "Data type: NotePlainType", which isnt limited to 255.

Comment: what do you mean by using List Settings or the actions on the right?  Can you be more specific?